# Magento 2 Get Current Store Date Time

Tags: magento2, date

In Magento 1.x you could get the store date time via

```
Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate();
```

What would be the equivalent to this in Magento 2.x?

Comment: does this return the current store time? I am getting the GMT time instead of PST time that Magento 2 store is set to.

Comment: \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date will return UTC (GMT). Use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface::formatDate(); for the current store date and time.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to inject in your class constructor an instance of `\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime` and use that one.
Something like this:

```
protected $date;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->date = $date;
    ....
}
```

Then, you can use in your class this:

```
$date = $this->date->gmtDate();
```

Comment: it gives gmt date how to get current store timezone wise date

Comment: I have tried this but it always giving a time difference of 5 hrs can you help me

Comment: How to get only time ?

Comment: @SanjayGohil. the method `gmtDate` shown above accepts 2 optional parameters. The first one is `$format` which defaults to `Y-m-d H:i:s`. You can just call the method with the parameter you want `gmtDate('H:i:s')` or any other time format.

Comment: How to add/subtract months into/from date by this method ?

Comment: @Marius, I need it to return the store time instead of GMT. What should I change?

Answer (score 24):

To get **UTC date** in Magento2 you should use `\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime::gmtDate();`

You should inject dependency on this class via construct and then use this function. See this class for more date/time related methods.

In your code sample you are retrieving UTC date, not store date. 
To get date formatted according to the **timezone of the current store**, use
`Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface::formatDate();` (again, by injecting dependency to construct)

Comment: For current store timezone this function give me only date not time so how can i get time also?

Comment: Take a look at `\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime::gmtTimestamp()`

Answer (score 15):

You can easily get Current Store Date Time by injecting in your class constructor in instance of `\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface` and use that one to get the DateObject.

For example:

```
protected $timezone;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $timezone,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->timezone = $timezone;
    ....
}
```

And then you can use it as followed:

```
$date = $this->timezone->formatDate();
```

For more information about different formats you can take a look at this article I wrote https://codeblog.experius.nl/magento-2-get-current-store-date-time/

Comment: What if i want to get timeZone ??

Comment: one can get timezone using this code $this->storeManager->getStore()->getConfig('general/locale/timezone'). and the dependency class for this would be \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,

Comment: @Mr. Lewis, this returns only the date. How do I get the time too?

Answer (score 7):

Magento 2.x have context objects for different classes, if you are in a context of Block then context object can give you locale date object as follows:

```
/**
 * Locale Date/Timezone
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface
 */
protected $_timezone;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_timezone = $context->getLocaleDate();
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $data
    );
}
```

then you can use it like following:

```
$todayDate = $this->_timezone->date()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

This will avoid errors while executing di:compile command.

Answer (score 6):

To get the current date time of a particular store (other than current store in StoreManager):

Reference from `\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Timezone::convertConfigTimeToUtc()`

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $timezone */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Timezone $timezone */

$timezone = $this->timezone->getConfigTimezone(\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORES, $storeId);
$currentDate = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone($timezone));
var_dump($currentDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

`\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime` will get you UTC date time, GMT date time or current store's date time.

Magento 2 sets UTC in `app/bootstrap`:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

`\DateTime` uses this PHP timezone setting by default.
Magento 2 will use internally UTC and it saves in MySQL in UTC also. Linux servers and MySQL servers usually are set to UTC timezone. The chain of the timezone settings on a server is not in scope of this topic.

Magento 2 will display on frontend the date in current store's timezone using locale resolver `\Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver` to get the current store timezone (e.g `Europe/Bruxelles`).

Answer (score 3):

We can set store timezone using observer with event "controller_action_predispatch"

Create events.xml in Mymodle/etc/frontend/events.xml folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="mymodule_timezone_set" instance="MyNamespace\Mymodule\Observer\SetStoreTimezoneObserver" />
    </event> </config>
```

In Observer folder create file SetStoreTimezoneObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace\Mymodule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SetStoreTimezoneObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $_storeTime;
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $timezone,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        $this->_storeTime = $timezone;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->setStoreTimezone();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve store model instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\Store\Model\Store
     */
    public function getStore()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore();
    }

    /*
     * Set Store Timezone
     */
    public function setStoreTimezone()
    {
        date_default_timezone_set(
            $this->_storeTime->getConfigTimezone('store', $this->getStore())
        );
    }

    /**
     * Predispath admin action controller
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $this->setStoreTimezone();
    }
}
```

Now instead of getting "UTC" date, we get current store date using simple date("Y-m-d H:i:s") function.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, if i use this on my controller, it doesn't work. I get the default locale date instead.

But if i use it on my block it works.

```
\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $timezone
$todayDate = $this->_timezone->date()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```