# Magento 2: How to get current date, date time with format in .phtml file?

Tags: magento2, phtml, date, datetime

I already referred [Magento 2 Get Current Store Date Time](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89623/magento-2-get-current-store-date-time)

But how to use directly in `.phtml` file? Can able to get Date, DateTime & Also able to set it's format?

Comment: Use directly  means ? you can use your template related block and render into a template (.phtml)

Comment: @krishnaijjadaati95Dev i would not like to pass values via Block/Controller

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this in `phtml` file :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$objDate = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime');
$date = $objDate->gmtDate();
```

But using directly object manager in `phtml` file is not a good practice.

Comment: It's giving `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime::gmtDate()` Using Magento 2

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: Got it. What about Format & how can i convert my Database other field's datetime in Y-m-d format??

Comment: You can change the date format using php date function like :
date('y-m-d', strtotime($date)). or any date format as you like

Comment: Can do with `$block->formatDate($_posts->getCreatedAt());` got it. No worries Thanks :)

Answer (score 22):

```
protected $_date;
 public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $date)
{
  $this->_date =  $date;
}
```

then use like this

```
$this->_date->date()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello i am using same \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface in my code but it displays different when i print that in file and is different in database. why??
in database i have type  "updated_at    timestamp"

Comment: The dateTime will  be difference because TimezoneInterface is working based on the Current TimeZone already setup on the Magento and also it will update value based on UTC..

Answer (score 0):

what if I want to give specific date here

```
$this->_date->date(<my-comment-date>)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```